# As of the Genshin 3.0 update, how many Dendroculus and Dendro sigils are available to unlock so far?

Tags: genshin-impact

As of the Genshin 3.0 update, how many Dendroculus and Dendro sigils are available to unlock so far?

I am now trying to not turn in any Dendroculus to the Statues of Seven, and not turn in any Dendro Sigils to the Tree of Dreams, in order to figure out exactly how many left I need to collect. Mostly an OCD thing, but I learned a painful lesson trying to find the last few remaining Electroculus in Inazuma long before gaining access to the Electroculus Resonance Stone. In Sumeru's case, it's also locked at rank 10, so I'd prefer being able to unlock all the Dendroculus before turning them in.

Comment: The Teyvat interactive map over on hoyolab.com has been updated with all their positions.

https://act.hoyolab.com/ys/app/interactive-map/index.html?bbs_presentation_style=no_header&utm_source=tools&lang=en-us&bbs_theme=dark&bbs_theme_device=1#/map/2?shown_types=42,2,3,154,197,403&center=3095.00,-3417.00&zoom=-1.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of time of writing, in version 3.1, the Hoyolab interactive map has these counts for the Oculi.

- Anemoculus **66**
- Geoculus **131**
- Electroculus **181**
- Dendroculus **180**

[image: Oculi collection list]

As for the Dendro Sigils, the [Tree of Dreams](https://gamewith.net/genshin-impact/article/show/34424) where you turn them in has 50 reward levels, and it costs 35 sigils per level.

So there *should* be 1750 sigils.

It's worth noting that some World Quests reward dendro sigils as a completion reward, and also levelling up the Statues of the Seven reward sigils.